# Header title and icons are misaligned on iOS after updating react-native@0.71.14?

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, react-navigation

my setup:

- expo SDK 48 (claims that it can only work with react-native@0.71.14)
- react-navigation/native 6.0.10
- only iOS is affected
- find my full package.json and code if you like here: https://github.com/tomwaitforitmy/mangi-bevi/blob/main/package-lock.json

react-native@0.71.8: all looks nice
[image]

react-native@0.71.14 on iOS (Android looks fine)
[image]

I found nothing in the react-native change log. I found no bug reports. I do not set any alignment for title or icons myself. If I downgrade to react-native@0.71.8 everything works. How can I narrow this down?